# Как передать переменную и выполнить API?

Tags: php, api

Есть API по отправке сообщения. Как правильно реализовать чтобы с HTML передалась значение  $phone и выполнилась данная функция

```
 <?php
    include('MesBy.php');
    $token = 'token';
    $phone = '999999999';
    $alphaname_id  = 001;
    $sms        = new MesBy($token);
    $res        = $sms->createSMSMessage('тест mess' ,  $alphaname_id);
    $message_id = $res->message_id;
    $res2       = $sms->sendSms($message_id, $phone);
    if ($res2 == false) {
        echo "Во время отправки сообщения произошла ошибка";
    } else {
        echo "Сообщение успешно отправлено, его ID: {$res2->sms_id}";
    }
```

Comment: Вам надо получить параметр из другого файла? Файл в  формате `php` или `html`?

Comment: "Надо написать правильный код, а неправильный код писать не нужно". 
Ну а если серьезно, то без понятия что у вас за API и как он работает. Вам нужно почитать про [как задавать вопросы на SO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Да. Т.е есть HTML, после ввода он передает их в API

Comment: Стоит прочитать про $_GET $_POST и передачу данных из браузера на сервер.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html

```
<a href="get.php?phone=12345">ссылка</a>
<!-- или из формы -->
<form name="f1" method="get" action="get.php">
телефон: <br />
<input name="phone" type="text" size="25" maxlength="30"/>
</form>
```

php

```
<?php
 $phone = $_GET['phone'];
....
?>
```